# Подключение .lib/.dll в Qt проект

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, gcc, сборка

Пытаюсь подключить в Qt проект на С++ (никакие собственные библиотеки Qt не используются) библиотеки ole32 и oleaut32 из набора windows SDK.

```
LIBS += -lole32
LIBS += -loleaut32
```

Библиотеки (.lib) лежат в директории проекта, он их видит, вроде видит так же и функции из них. Но выдает ~1000 ошибок в .h файлах библиотек. Видимо эти либы скомпилированы в msvc, qt же работает через mingw, в этом и проблема (как мне кажется). Есть ли способ все таки подключить их без ошибок используя Qt? Может нужно подключить не lib а dll файлы? Или они так же зависят от компилятора? Знаний именно в этой области не достает, видимо я что-то важное упустил

Comment: Может есть инструменты для чтобы перекомпилить MSCV либы в MinGW?

Answer (score 3):

.dll или .lib зависит от способа линковки. Если вы не уверены, то скорей всего, она динамическая, а значит .dll

Попробуйте добавить еще

```
LIBS += -lole32 -luuid
```

Ну и кроме того при переносе проекта из студии в QtCreator и смене компилятора многие вещи, которые старый компилятор проглатывал, MinGW не примет. Придется переделывать код. QtCreator, если я не ошибаюсь, будет пофайлово выводить ошибки и предупреждения. То есть не все ошибки в проекте сразу, а файл за файлом

Comment: Попробовал добавить -luuid  - ничего не изменилось. Сейчас обратил внимание, что все ошибки в файле oleauto.h, то есть только у второй библиотеки косяки. А так у меня оба файла есть и lib и dll для каждой из библиотек

Comment: А ко второй LIBS собственно пробовали это добавлять? Т.е. `LIBS += -loleaut32 -luuid`

Comment: Да, пробовал конечно. Неужели здесь попадаются люди, которым нужно все пошагово и буквально объяснять?) Тем не менее спасибо за дотошность, ведь варианта, кроме как через dlltool сделать мингв либу из длл.

Answer (score 0):

Может пригодиться а может и нет. Если в проекты необходимо импортировать внешние библиотеки и файлы очень удобно пользоваться уже готовой функцией импортирования Qt. Правой клавишей нажать на проект->Добавить библиотеку->Добавить внешнюю библиотеку->путь к либе. Самое удобное что путь в про файл пропишется правильно сам.

Comment: Да пробовал так, но при выборе пути к либе, он становился красным, и кнопка "Далее" становилась неактивная) разбираться не стал

Comment: походу это только .lib, то есть для динамической линковки не катит